# {detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."} on get request with simplejwt

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I saw alot of similar questions but those questions are not working for me. I really have no idea why I can't access the api. I have test it with the token in postman and it returned correct data. Can you correct me please.

backend

```
# model
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100

# viewset
class DepartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DepartmentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

#setting.py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

frontend

```
# axios-base.js
import axios from "axios";

const getAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    timeout: 1000,
})

export {getAPI}

#template.vue
<script>
import { getAPI } from "../../src/axios-base.js";
export default {
  name: "Department",
  data() {
    return {
      departments: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getAllDepartment();
  },
  methods: {
    getAllDepartment: function() {
      const token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl9....."; <- access token
      getAPI.get("/attendance-rest-api/departments/",
          {
              email: "admin@gmail.com", <- admin account
              password: "admin",
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.departments = res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

my api json view

```
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/attendance-rest-api/departments/1/",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "GIC"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/attendance-rest-api/departments/2/",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "GEE"
    },
```

error i got in terminal django

```
Unauthorized: /attendance-rest-api/departments/
[20/Sep/2020 13:18:04] "GET /attendance-rest-api/departments/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

error i got in browser

```
detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing Axios API. In GET requests, only one parameter - `config` object - should be passed into the corresponding method, and params should be passed inside `params` property of that object. Like this:

```
getAPI.get("/attendance-rest-api/departments/",
  {
    params: {
      email: "admin@gmail.com", <- admin account
      password: "admin",
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
)
```

With the existing code, that second object (containing headers) is just ignored, causing the error you see.

---

As a sidenote, I'm really not sure why do you use GET here. Not only usually having passwords as params of GETs is a (very) bad idea; in this case, however, it's not even clear what's the purpose.

I suspect you just combined the code from some POST requests (for login scenario, perhaps?). But again, GETs and POSTs are really different beasts.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm learning to use django rest framework and axios that's why i'm a bit confuse about it. Here is the whole purpose. I want to get data from Department model and display it inside the register form to allow user to choose which department they are in (ManytoMany relationship) and in the viewset of `Department` i set the permission to `IsAdminUser` so i thought i have to pass the admin account in get request to get access to api. But I will try to read more about axios and django rest framework.

Comment: If you want something to be shown in registration form, it's essentially public information (as you don't know anything about your user _before_ they registered).

Comment: You're right!  I think I had some misunderstandings about it. Thanks you sir !!